# Angular - How to pass config to a module loaded by another module using `forRoot`?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm struggling trying to figure out how to solve this injection problem.

I have ModuleA (mapbox) that requires a token, and ModuleB that imports ModuleA.

The problem is that ModuleB is a library module, which therefore should be configured. So I'd like to give the ability to the final users to do something like this:

`ModuleB.forRoot({mapboxToken: 'some-token'});`

And under the hood the ModuleB should pass that token to the ModuleA `withConfig` method.
Right now I have to do this in the ModuleB.

`imports: [ModuleA.withConfig({token: 'some hardcoded token'});`

Any suggestions on how to do this in the proper Angular way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved by myself

For anyone interested here's how I did it:

```
import { NgxMapboxGLModule, MAPBOX_API_KEY } from 'ngx-mapbox-gl';

export interface IWVMapModuleConfig {
    mapboxToken: string;
}

export const WVMapModuleConfig = new InjectionToken<IWVMapModuleConfig>('IWVMapModuleConfig');

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxMapboxGLModule,
    ],
})
export class WVMapModule {
    static forRoot(config: IWVMapModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders<WVMapModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: WVMapModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: MAPBOX_API_KEY,
                    useValue: config.mapboxToken,
                },
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

Then in the application root module:

```
    ...
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ...
        WVMapModule.forRoot({
            mapboxToken: 'your-token-here'
        })
    ]
    ...
```

Comment: but this solution doesn't seem to be doing what you asked, imo - I'm curious cause I need to do a similar thing now where ModuleA imports ModuleB and both need configuration, and ModuleB needs some of the configuration to be based on the configuration of ModuleA. Then ModuleA is imported in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had 3 different layered libraries and a top level app. Each layer has to add some layer config to the top level config object. I used the following approach.

The DI is setup first and each layer overrides it's lower layer config (using `{ provide: ..., useExisting: ... }`) so by the time the constructors are called on each module they are getting passed the same config object. The constructor is where I add the layer specific config.

```
// MY APP MODULE
const config: ModuleCConfig = {
  api: "/my-api",
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleC.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ModuleCConfig, useValue: config }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }



// MODULE C
export class ModuleCConfig : ModuleBConfig {
 // Addition properties...
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleB.forRoot(),
]})
export class ModuleC {

  constructor(config: ModuleCConfig){
        // Add additional info to the top level config
  }
  
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ModuleC> {
    return {
      ngModule: ModuleC,
      providers: [
        { provide: ModuleBConfig, useExisting: ModuleCConfig },
      ],
    };
  }
}



// MODULE B
export class ModuleBConfig : ModuleAConfig {
 // Addition properties...
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleA,
]})
export class ModuleB {

  constructor(config: ModuleBConfig){
        // Add additional info to the top level config
  }
  
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ModuleB> {
    return {
      ngModule: ModuleB,
      providers: [
        { provide: ModuleAConfig, useExisting: ModuleBConfig },
      ],
    };
  }
}


// MODULE A
export class ModuleAConfig {
    api: string;
}

@NgModule({})
export class ModuleA {
  constructor(config: ModuleAConfig){
        // Add additional info to the top level config
  }
}
```